# Как преобразовать JSON строку приходящую в консоль в объект выводимый на сайт с помощью JS?

Tags: javascript, html, json

Всем привет!
Такой вопрос, посылается запрос на сервер и приходит ответ JSON в виде строки в консоль, но нужно эти значения вывести в виде объекта на страницу сайта

```js
function select_company()
{
  var chbx_list = collect_checkboxes();
  var amount = chbx_list.length;
  console.log(chbx_list);
  csrf_token = $('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val();
  $.ajax({
      url : "/blockchain/", // the endpoint убрать первыйс слуеш в случае неудачи
      type : "POST", // http method
      data : {chbx_amount : amount,
              checks_list : chbx_list,
              csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrf_token }, // data sent with the post request

              success : function(json) {
                  console.log(json)
                  },

                  // handle a non-successful response
                  error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {

                  }
      });
      return false;
}
```

Comment: преобразуйте в объект, а там делайте с ним чего хотите. В чем проблема-то?

Comment: var incomeJson = JSON.parse(json); // convert it to an object

Answer (score 1):

можно просто вывести его в элемент pre

```js
function select_company()
{
  var chbx_list = collect_checkboxes();
  var amount = chbx_list.length;
  console.log(chbx_list);
  csrf_token = $('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val();
  $.ajax({
      url : "/blockchain/", // the endpoint убрать первыйс слуеш в случае неудачи
      type : "POST", // http method
      data : {chbx_amount : amount,
              checks_list : chbx_list,
              csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrf_token }, // data sent with the post request

              success : function(json) {
                    let incomeJson = JSON.parse(json);
                    //объект incomeJson делайте что угодно с ним
                    let newPre = document.createElement(pre);
                    newPre = JSON.stringify(incomeJson, null, ' ');
                    document.body.appendChield(newPre);
                  },

                  // handle a non-successful response
                  error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {

                  }
      });
      return false;
}
```